# Spring hibernate multi thread

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a requirement that when client adds an entry to database an email should be generated and sent to the user. I am using spring+hibernate here. Sending email will be done in a seperate thread so that client do not need to wait until email is sent . Sample code snippet -

```
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
                return sessionFactory;
 }

 public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
 }

 @Override
 @Transactional
 public boolean addEntry()
 {
    Log log = new Log();
    //setters
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.save(log);

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        @Transactional
        public void run() {
            Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            Query query = session.createQuery(" get employee email query");

            // send email
        }
    });
    thread.start();
    return true;
}
```

I am getting an error at session getting code inside run method as

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
```

How can i make multi-thread to work in a spring - hibernate application ? Please help.

Comment: Well obviously not like that. Also creating threads is basically something you shouldn't do in an application. Make another method and simply annotate it with `@Async` and configure a `TaskExecutor` accordingly. First insert the user, afterwards call the method for sending an email.

Comment: You could simply write the record and return to the user as fast as possible. Then, create a scheduled task that polls the db for new records, and send a mail as needed. If you schedule the mail job every 5 minutes or so, the users will get their mail in a reasonable amount of time, and they won't block on the email sends.

Comment: @M.Deinum So you are saying if i use a method with '@Async' annotation ,   the main execution will not wait for the async method to conclude ? ( This is actually what i want )

Comment: The main issue is here , i am unable to use session factory inside the run() method . Why is it so ?

Comment: Because the `@Transactional` doesn't have any use here. However I strongly suggest not to create threads as that is basically forbidden by the JEE spec (in a JEE server). Use the appropriate tools for it.

Comment: @M.Deinum I created one method with `@Async` annotation and invoked that method before returning . But the main thread still wait for sendemail method to finish . What's wrong here ?

`@Override
 @Transactional
 public boolean addEntry()
 {
   .
   .
    session.save(log);

    // call send email method
    sendemail();
    return true;
}

@Transactional
@Async
public void sendemail()
{
 Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
  
 Query query = session.createQuery("from "+ Employee.class.getName());
 
}`

Comment: Please don't add code as comments as that is unreadable. Internal method calls won't work you  have to declare it on another service. Also make sure you have enabled async support (`@EnableAsync` on the configuration) and that you have configured a `TaskExecutor` for multiple threads else everything still is synchronous. I suggest a read of the spring reference guide on the matter instead of trial and error.